# I'm trying to enumerate some things in the middle of a sentence

Tags: grammar, punctuation, syntactic-analysis

I'm currently writing my thesis paper and i'm trying to enumerate some stuff in the middle of the sentence.

It goes like this.

"The results of the study will be able to describe and give useful insights on the call centers and their human resource practices in Iloilo City to greatly benefit its stakeholders namely, call centers, call center agents, prospective call center agents, and other potential stakeholders."

or should I separate it into two sentences like this?

"The results of the study will be able to describe and give useful insights on the call centers and their human resource practices in Iloilo City to greatly benefit its stakeholders. Call centers, call center agents, prospective call center agents, and other potential stakeholders."

Comment: The results of the study will enable readers to describe, and will give other useful insights on, the call centers and their human resource practices in Iloilo City. This will greatly benefit its stakeholders (call centers, call center agents, prospective call center agents, and other potential stakeholders).

Comment: I'd prefer two shorter sentences as follows: "The results of the study will be able to describe and give useful insights on the call centers and their human resource practices in Iloilo City. This will greatly benefit its stakeholders, that is, call centers, call center agents, prospective call center agents, and other potential stakeholders."

Comment: Oh. That's way better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first example works, but it would be most normal to have the comma before namely, rather than after.

The second example is not correct because the second sentence is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I think I like the one with parenthesis better.

Thanks again!